# Handling NULL in Dropdown list from Entity Framework Stored Proc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem with nulls that are being returned from a stored procedure.  I have a drop down list that I want to be initially blank, but then contain unique street types.  That way the user can either leave the field blank to return all results, or start typing and get suggestions from the possible entries that DO exist.

The list is unique street types that is retrieved from a stored procedure that just does a DISTINCT query on the main table of all addresses.  However I get a NULL in the result and my drop down list seems to stop showing results once it hits that null.

I'm using Entity framework and added the stored procedure that returns a set of strings, then used the following code to populate the combo box.  If I leave no ordering in the stored proc the null is in the middle somewhere and I get half of the results, if I order it so the null is first I get no results in my combobox.

```
 SideSewerDAL.SideSewerEntities entities = new SideSewerDAL.SideSewerEntities();
 comboType.DataSource = entities.GetUniqueStreetTypes();
```

So am I going about this wrong?  Should I get rid of the NULL in my storedproc and somehow fix the combobox to add a "blank" entry?  Or keep the NULL but somehow make the combobox handle the nulls rather than choke!  Here is the code for the stored proc

```
    public ObjectResult<global::System.String> GetUniqueStreetTypes()
    {
        return base.ExecuteFunction<global::System.String>("GetUniqueStreetTypes");
    }
```

Comment: If you return "" from your sproc instead of NULL does it work?

Comment: Once you get the result from the database,  just add a new empty item there. Make sure you except the NULL from the sproc.

Comment: It does Mike.  I had to redo the stored procedure as follows: SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(stType,'') as stType
 FROM SideSewer.dbo.SSCard 
 ORDER BY stType

Comment: I suggest you keep the UI issues away from the database. Adding the empty string should be at the UI since its specific to UI issue.

Comment: I'm going to try it that way as well, removing nulls from the stored procedure and ONLY giving unique street types.  However I'm not sure how to add the blank entry to the combobox if it's bound to a datasource like above?

Comment: I think the fundamental question here is whether the null value is a valid value returned from your stored procedure. If it is valid what it means? If it is not valid then the fix is in the stored procedure. Btw. do you need the store procedure at all? It seems like an ad hoc query here would work and would be much simpler to make it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure returns a list of strings, you can create a list of strings, add the "" value, then add the range returned from the sproc.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("");
values.AddRange(entities.GetUniqueStreetTypes());
comboType.DataSource = values;
```

As for dealing with the nulls, the best solution might be best to include "WHERE stType IS NOT NULL"